# npm install no me funciona, no hay caso

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm

llevo tiempo tratando de instalar las dependencias de un repositorio desarrollando con angular-cli pero al intentarlo me hace el odioso...

> npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed: ....

Leyendo dicen que es por un tema de red.. por proxy... resulta que mi PC no usa proxy y tengo buena acceso a la red y he probado quitando el cortafuegos.

Que podria pasar realmente? ayuda por favor.

```html
npm version 5.6.0
node version v8.11.4
```

Comment: Estás ejecutando el comando en el directorio correcto?

Comment: Si claro...donde esta el pkg json

Comment: Tienes el proyecto en una carpeta que no necesita permisos de administrador?